# generating subdocuments with doxygen

Tags: c++, pdf, latex, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have a large C++ software application documented with doxygen. How can I set it up so that I can generate subdocuments for specific classes? The classes are documented with in-source commenting, their own .dox files, and images/ directory. I need to be able to generate a standalone pdf file specific to a single class.

I can use grouping to identify what will be included in that subdocument, but how do I generate output for a single group?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific .dox file per requested output entity, then all you need to do is define in that file as input the files declaring and defining that class.

Say for example you want an output only for class `MyClass` which is declared in file `myclass.hpp` and whose implementation is in `myclass.cpp`, then in `myclass.dox`, just add this:

```
INPUT = ./myclass.cpp \
    ./myclass.hpp
```

Of course, you can have different paths for .cpp and .hpp. Or you can document more than one class.

Then, run doxygen on that `myclass.dox` file.

Also watch out for the output folder name. For the html output, the default name is `html` so you might want to rename it to avoid mixing up all the different outputs. For example, you might want to add in the dox file something like:

```
HTML_OUTPUT = html_myclass
```